# Trying to create a Site Collection using PS but keep getting error

Tags: 2010, powershell, site-collection

I am trying to create a site collection using powershell script but keep getting error even though I already created Managed Path I am referencing in cmdlet,

```
PS C:\Users\svc_spadmin> New-SPManagedPath "Teams" -WebApplication "http://share
point2010/"

Name                           Type
----                           ----
teams                          WildcardInclusion


PS C:\Users\svc_spadmin> New-SPSite -URL "http://sharepoint2010/teams" -ownerAli
as "sp\svc_spadmin" -Template "STS#0"
```

> New-SPSite : A site collection could not be created as the provided
>   managed pat h does not exist.  Change the URL to use an existing
>   managed path or create the  missing managed path prior to calling this
>   command. At line:1 char:11
>   + New-SPSite <<<<  -URL "http://sharepoint2010/Teams" -ownerAlias "sp\svc_spadm in" -Template "STS#0"
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...SPCmdletNewSite:    SPCmdletNewSite) [New-SPSite],
>   SPCmdletException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewSite

**Edit**

```
PS C:\Users\svc_spadmin> New-SpManagedPath -RelativeURL "MPOne" -WebApplication
"http://sharepoint2010/"

Name                           Type
----                           ----
mpone                          WildcardInclusion



PS C:\Users\svc_spadmin> New-SPSite -URL "http://sharepoint2010/mpone/testsite"
-ownerAli "sp\svc_spadmin" -Template "STS#0"
```

> New-SPSite : The URL '/mpone/testsite' is invalid.  It may refer to a
>   nonexiste nt file or folder, or refer to a valid file or folder that
>   is not in the curren t Web. At line:1 char:11
>   + New-SPSite <<<<  -URL "http://sharepoint2010/mpone/testsite" -ownerAli "sp\sv c_spadmin" -Template "STS#0"
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...SPCmdletNewSite:    SPCmdletNewSite) [New-SPSite],
>   SPException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewSite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a managed path named teams, now you actually need to create a site collection under this managed path. So you should name the site collection url something like "http://sharepoint2010/teams/testsite.Follwoing should be the PS command:

```
New-SPSite -URL "http://sharepoint2010/teams/testsite" -ownerAli
as "sp\svc_spadmin" -Template "STS#0"
```

Moreover, the correct way of creating the managed path is

```
New-SPManagedPath –RelativeURL "Teams" -WebApplication "http://share
point2010/"
```

The above script will create wild card inclusion, If you want explicit inclusion just add
-Explicit

Comment: Thanks, I tried it before and again now but it didn't worked

Comment: I just checked it on my VM and a site collection is created successfully. Can you see the managed path being created in the UI. Can you try creating a new webapplication and see if the script works there.

Comment: It worked on new web application but I am still confused why it didn't worked on default one created by SharePoint while farm wizard tho